# How To Load jQuery JSON using onLoad. Obtaining City & State from Zipcode On Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, zipcode

I am by no means an expert coder and have been struggling with this all day. I am trying to autofill the city and state based on the zip code in my website's contact form. I have found a nice jQuery thing called Ziptastic. I do a JSON call (I think that's what its called) and this retrieves the data from the Ziptastic website. Here is Ziptastic: http://daspecster.github.com/ziptastic/demo.html

Here is the code I have that pulls the code from the Ziptastic website and enters the city & state into my contact form:

```
        $(document).on("keyup", "#zip", function(){
          var zip = this.value;
          $.getJSON('http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/' + zip, function(json) {
            $('#city').val(json.city);
          });
          $.getJSON('http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com?zip=' + zip, function(json) {
            $('#state').val(json.state);
          });
        });
```

My form works well now and is updating my city and state fields after I enter AND KEYUP on the zipcode field. However here is the problem... My website visitor enters their zip-code on my website homepage which is posted to my contact form on this page where I am trying to auto-fill the city and state. I need to click into the field and click out for it to update.

I need the City and State to autofill immediately (onload).

I cannot figure out how to make this code onLoad with the zipcode value that is posted to my contact form from my homepage.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this with Javascript, you'd have to use the same `getJSON` code that you've been using, except you'd actually have to echo the value of the POSTed field into the code instead of using `+ zip`... something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com?zip=<?php echo $_POST['zip']; ?>', function(json) {
     $('#state').val(json.state);
});
```

(assuming you're using PHP here. It would be pretty much equivalent in other languages though; I'm sure you can figure that part out.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var zip = $("#zip").val();
      $.getJSON('http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/' + zip, function(json) {
        $('#city').val(json.city);
      });
      $.getJSON('http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com?zip=' + zip, function(json) {
        $('#state').val(json.state);
      });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks guys this works great! Aaron, I used your solution and it is perfect.